# How to work in Spotify, Python API?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I have installed Spotipy on my machine using these direction: https://github.com/plamere/spotipy

I am trying to run one of the examples but nothing is happening only the file opens. Here is the code they give:

## shows artist info for a URN or URL

```
import spotipy
import sys
import pprint

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    search_str = sys.argv[1]
else:
    search_str = 'Radiohead'

sp = spotipy.Spotify()
result = sp.search(search_str)
pprint.pprint(result)
```

When I type "search.py" into the cmd prompt the file opens. Nothing else happens. I thought it would print out something related to Radiohead but no.

Do I need to do anything else?

Update 10/28/2017

I have made sure that the request package is installed.

I get bunch of errors, it looks like client.py is giving me errors. It also says I need to provide a token but this code should not need a token.

Python command and errors with Spotipy

[image]

Comment: Do you have the requests package installed?

Comment: When you say you're typing "search.py" into the command prompt what do you mean, i.e. "python search.py"?

Comment: I have installed the request package.

Comment: python search.py did not work so I had to use py search.py

Comment: https://httpstatuses.com/401

Comment: Thank You for all your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error 401 is generated when you try to access a resource and you are not authenticated. `Spotify` currently requires that you provide your credentials for it you must register in the following [link](https://developer.spotify.com/my-applications) and create an application in it, in the end it will provide you with the `Client ID` and `Client Secret`, these values must be placed in the part indicated by the code.

```
import sys
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy
import pprint

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    search_str = sys.argv[1]
else:
    search_str = 'Radiohead'

client_id = "your_client_id"
client_secret = "your_client_secret"

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

result = sp.search(search_str)
pprint.pprint(result)
```